# Is this proof of mine regarding prime numbers correct?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm required to prove the following in the textbook:

> Prove that if $p_1, p_2, \ldots p_n$ are distinct prime numbers with $p_1 = 2$ and $n > 1$, then $p_1 \cdot p_2 \ldots p_n +1$ can be written in the form $4k+3$ for some integer $k$.

My approach is as follows:

From the quotient-remainder theorem, we know that $p_1 \cdot p_2 \ldots p_n +1$ has to be of one of the following forms:

1) $4k$

2) $4k + 1$

3) $4k + 2$

4) $4k + 3$

Now, since $p_1 = 2$, we have a number of the form $2r+1$, which rules out options 1) and 3). If option 2) is compared with the given number, we get a common factor of 4, which is not possible if all the numbers are prime. Thus we are left with option 4) only.

Is this reasoning correct or have I jumped the gun somewhere?

Comment: Your argument is correct, but you may want to clarify what you mean by "we get a common factor of $4$, which ...", since as written, it is hard to decipher. I added a slightly faster argument as an answer.

Comment: Works for me...

Comment: Thanks a lot, @hardmath! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The $p_i$ with $i>1$ are all odd, so their product $p_2\dots p_n$ is odd, say $2r+1$. Then $p_1\cdot(p_2\dots p_n)+1=2(2r+1)+1=4r+3$.

Comment: Much more elegant! Why can't I seem to come up with such beautiful approaches? :(

Comment: @dotslash as smart as Andres Caicedo is and as lovely as this answer is, your intuition and approaches will improve with time. The more math you're exposed to and work through yourself, the more easily these kinds of insights will come to you. It's also worth noting that it's good to work through things the "hard" way sometimes - it can yield deeper insights into the heart of the problem that a slick approach might miss. Keep at it!

Comment: Thank you very much for the encouragement, @AWertheim! It's a boon to have this community! :)

Comment: From experience, typically the first proofs one finds are not the most elegant ones: They are like crooked roads, full of detours and meanders. By studying them, one can sometimes see how to shorten them, by recognizing bits that upon reflection turn out to be superfluous. Of course, time and experience help, as one learns to recognize short cuts. To illustrate, consider your proof. If one applies the reasoning you used in the $4k+1$ case to the $4k+3$ case, one sees that all that is needed is that $p_2\dots p_n$ is odd. Since this is true, we can rearrange this into the argument above.

Comment: Rightly said, @AndresCaicedo! Many thanks for your participation! :)